# The output of formulas in the latex format with two columns style

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, two-column

I am writing a paper for a springier journal. The latex style of this journal is based on the two columns format.

I have some equations in my paper and I want to write these equations in 
paragraphs in the style $equation$ and not in an independent
line by applying command $$equation$$.

My problem is that in some cases, equations do not split in a line 
and continue its rest in the next line.

For example, consider the following code

```
\documentclass[pdftex,twocolumn,epjc3]{svjour3}       
\begin{document}

Therefore, we conclude that 
$Reg_i=h(h(ID_i \|R_i \| HPW_i )  \bmod m), A_i=R_i\oplus HPW_i, B_i=h(ID_i 
\|R_i \|K), C_i=B_i\oplus h(ID_i\oplus R_i\oplus HPW_i)$,
which results in our conditions are satisfied by the assumptions and hence 
we can continue other steps. 

\end{document}
```

The output of the mentioned code is in the following form

[image: The output of the code]

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edition:** Although when we run the code with following form

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

the mentioned problem is solved, while we apply the next command

```
\documentclass[pdftex,twocolumn,epjc3]{svjour3}
```

we get the following output

[image: Edited output]

I think the command \linebreak[0] dose not work over svjour3.cls.

Comment: don't change the textwidth or add `\fussy` to the journal class! that would invalidate the article for journal use. I was just using article and made those settings to approximate the same column width. `\linebreak` will work but you may need it in slighltly different places. You can use `\linebreak` rather than `\linebreak[0]` to force a linebreak rather than suggest it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You right, It works. Really really Thanks. You are man of Tex.

Comment: If it takes more than one line, use display math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\advance\textwidth20pt
\fussy
\begin{document}

Therefore, we conclude that 
$Reg_i=h(h(ID_i \|R_i \| HPW_i )  \bmod m), A_i=R_i\oplus HPW_i, B_i=h(ID_i 
\|R_i \|K), C_i=B_i\oplus h(ID_i\oplus R_i\oplus HPW_i)$,
which results in our conditions are satisfied by the assumptions and hence 
we can continue other steps. 


Therefore, we conclude that 
$\mathrm{Reg}% never math italic for multi-letter names
_i=h(h(ID_i \|R_i \|\linebreak[0]
 HPW_i )  \bmod m), A_i=R_i\oplus HPW_i, B_i=h(ID_i 
\|R_i \|K),\linebreak[0]
 C_i=B_i\oplus h(ID_i\oplus R_i\oplus HPW_i)$,
which results in our conditions are satisfied by the assumptions and hence 
we can continue other steps. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: the preamble settings just to approximate the journal class (looking at your output image) as I don't have it

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions. I edited the question and explain the next problem. Thanks again for your useful answer.